# Problem with Boolean-difference modifier – or – How to model a cuboid with two cylindric holes

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers

Simplified: I want to generate a cuboid with cylinders as holes in Blender.
[image: i need to remove/difference the Cylinders and only want to keep the cube with the hole]
When I add with a difference-modifier, I come to pretty common problems/limitations. 
[image: i run into open face...]

There are lots of tips or advice like about this theme:
-   Solidify the objects before booleaning them 
-   Recalculating normals
-   Close holes
I couldn’t fix the problem with this general advice. I know that these are the limitations of face-based modelling (with Blender) and not volume-based (other software) modelling. But there must be a work around for Blender?
I know a manual fix for this problem:

By manually and step adding the faces (in the Edit Mode by selection one edge and pressing [enter])
[image: Closing the Hole of the first Cilinder]

Well at least it is nearly a solution…

[image: Problems by filling 2 intersecting cylinders]

But anyway, this isn't helpful for a scripted solution...
So what can I do?
Can someone tell me how to code this?

---

## code Example of this Problem for Blender 2.80b (warning, this seems to be not backwards compatible with Blender 2.79):

```
#code for Blender 2.80
import bpy

def booleanModifierApplyAndDelete(fromObject, removeObject):
        ##Switch to 
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects[fromObject]
        bpy.data.objects[fromObject].select_set(state=True)

        ##addModifier Working
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='BOOLEAN')
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Boolean"].operation = 'DIFFERENCE'
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Boolean"].object = bpy.data.objects[removeObject]
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier="Boolean")
        bpy.data.objects.remove(bpy.data.objects[removeObject], do_unlink=True)   


#initial variables:

thickness = 2
width = 5
height = 2
overlap = 0.1


#delete all objects from previous Build
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)


##add mainCube
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0,0,0))
bpy.context.active_object.name = 'mainCube'
bpy.context.object.dimensions = (thickness,width,height)



#top Rounding/hole
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(vertices=64, radius=1-overlap/2*2, depth=width+overlap*2, view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 1), rotation=(1.5708, 0, 0))
bpy.context.active_object.name = 'topRounding'

booleanModifierApplyAndDelete('mainCube', 'topRounding')


#cylindrical hole
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(vertices=64, depth=height+overlap*2, view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0))
bpy.context.active_object.name = 'hole'

booleanModifierApplyAndDelete('mainCube', 'hole')
```

Comment: Have you tried adding subdivisions/more edge loops to the original mesh? That can sometimes help.

Answer (score 3):

Because an intersection between two cylinders at 90 degrees is a 45 degree miter, this isn't too hard to model. Z up, Y along the lenght, X across

[image]

1. <kbd>K</kbd> with <kbd>C</kbd> to constrain and <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through, make 2 45 degree cuts into  a half-cylinder as shown
2. <kbd>E</kbd> (right-click to cancel transform) followed by <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> extrude the long edges outwards
3. Select all the faces, <kbd>E</kbd> extrude them downwards, followed by <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> about their median point to flatten them.
4. Select the central hole-faces on both sides, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > Bridge Edge Loops
5. Header select menu > Select Sharp Edges, and add some by hand to complete the circumference of the top hole. Set the Bevel Weight of all the selected edges to 1.00

Assign a Bevel modifier by Weight, Segments 2, Profile 1.00. I usually switch off the clamps, and reduce the width until everything looks correct. Assign a Subdivision Surface modifier.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the simplest way, without code, in Blender 2.80 Beta. I use the Bool Tool activated in the Add-ons in the Preferences.

1. Select the 2 cylinders, press <kbd>n</kbd> to bring up the panel, if not showing, and click on the Tools tab to show the Bool Tools.

[image]

2. Union them, now you have only one cylinder object, see below.

[image]

3. With this latest cylinder selected, add the cube to the selection and Difference them. Now you have the desired object shape.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you.
My Beta version wasn't containing the Bool Tools in the Settings. So i downloaded the latest version. 
I tried to reproduce every step... 
The N key just opend the Objectmenu, so i used [strg]+[shift]+[B]. 
But i could not reproduce your result and was left with the open surface like before (the second picture in the question).

Comment: Okay, there seems to be a problem with the modifier, when the axis of the cylinder is located exactly in the surface of the cube. When I slightly move the cylinder, it works just fine.

Comment: May need to report it as a bug then. Must have been a really old beta. The Bool Tool is part of the beta for a while. For the 'n' key to work you need to hover your cursor over the modeling window you are working on. Feel free to mark my answer as a solution if it solved your problem.

Comment: Forgot to mention, to report a bug go to the Help menu and select Report a Bug menu item. The guys are very responsive there. If it is found to be a bug, they will resolve it in a few days, that is my experience. Give as much information as you can, if possible with images or sample blender file that has the problem and a very clear explanation.